# Gradle falsely determines Jar task UP-TO-DATE

Tags: gradle, adoptopenjdk, netbeans-12

I recently got a peculiar problem when developing a hobby project in Java together with three friends. We are all using Adopt OpenJDK 15, Netbeans 12.1, and Gradle 6.8. The project is a Gradle multi-project build consisting of several projects, of which one is a library used by the other projects. The library uses the plugin `java-library`.

Now to the issue, which is that for one of us, no Jar files are produced, despite we all use the same identical source code. After some troubleshooting, we think that Gradle is the culprit in this. However, we cannot understand why it works flawlessly for everyone else.

For the one experiencing this issue, the library project (which has no dependencies on other projects within the multi-project) can be successfully compiled and built, but no jar file is produced. The jar task is simply considered  `UP-TO-DATE`. This will cause any subsequent builds depending on this library to fail. Forcing Gradle to run the task using the `--rerun-tasks` flag will generate the Jar which got us to the conclusion about Gradle being the cause. It looks like it fails to detect that the task needs to be rerun.

We've tried to reinstall both the JDK and Netbeans, as well as Gradle (which is managed via Netbeans), but the issue seems persistent. Now we've run out of ideas of how to come on terms with this, and put our hopes to that someone has been experiencing this before and can point us in the right direction.